# Transforming the array of object for Highcharts input?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am really struggling with the Object transformation. I have an array of Object and want to transform it into [Highcharts multi line chart input](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic). I want to get the unique dates first sorted from low to high, which will go into x axis and then transform the `Original` based on `ID` and `date`. The length for each `ID.data` is going to remain same (for whatever date `count` is not available for that date it will come as null)

Original:

```
 [
            {
                "date": "1997-09-29",
                "Count": 100,
                "ID": "AB12-R"
            },
            {
                "date": "1997-12-30",
                "Count": 104.7,
                "ID": "AB13-R"
            },
            {
                "date": "1998-03-30",
                "Count": 981,
                "ID": "BA12-R"
            },
            {
                "date": "1998-06-01",
                "Count": 341,
                "ID": "BA12-R"
            }
        ]
```

Transformed:

```
[{
Identiy : 'AB12-R',
data : [100,null,null,null]
},
{
Identiy : 'AB13-R',
data : [null,104.7,null,null]
},{
Identiy : 'BA12-R',
data : [null,null,981,341]
}]
```

I have tried with reduce but nothing is working it seems. I am able to group it by ID but not able to handle the null and missing count, Can someone please help me here ?

This is what i have tried:

```
  const result = Original.reduce(function (r, a) {
    r[a.ID] = r[a.ID] || [];
    r[a.ID].push(a);
    return r;
  }, Object.create(null));
  console.log({'Transformed':result})
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this solution:

```
const hcData = [];

data.forEach((d, i) => {

  const checkIfExist = hcData.find(data => data.id === d["ID"])

  if (checkIfExist) {
    checkIfExist.data[i] = d["Count"];
  } else {
    const initialData = [...Array(data.length)]
    initialData.fill(null, 0, data.length)

    initialData[i] = d["Count"];
    hcData.push({
      data: initialData,
      id: d["ID"]
    })
  }
})
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k2dg1wns/

Comment: Its not working properly, Please check this case: https://jsfiddle.net/v3mtc5kw/ I have added the expected data at the bottom.

Exp:  It should have only 3 entries because there is only 3 unique dates

Comment: It is working properly - just like you described in the issue - null is assigned in the place where is no data point.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But In my question the size of data depends on unique dates available in original data. Right now its 4 because there are 4 unique dates, Can you please help me in modifying the logic a bit to handle this case ?

Comment: So to be sure you would like to identify data by ID and date?